# Accessing Object Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

somewhat new to Javascript and just needed some help on the following.
Example from Eloquent Javascript.

```
var journal = [];

function addEntry(events, didITurnIntoASquirrel) {
journal.push({
    events: events,
    squirrel: didITurnIntoASquirrel
   });
}

 addEntry(['work', 'lunch', 'peanuts', 'exercise'], false);

console.log(journal[0]);
```

How do i get the console to list the journal array?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(journal);`

Comment: console.log(journal); just outputs [Object] in the console. How would i list the entire array?

Comment: `console.dir(journal);`

Comment: Have you ever heard about `loop`? And this is not what you're asking.

Comment: Check again. `journal` is an array according to your code snippet

Comment: Be more precise. By "list the journal array", do you mean "list the array which is part of the first element in the journal array"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get at the array located at the first entry in the journal array you could access it using the index and the events variable name.

```
console.log(journal[0].events);
```